# netbeans 6.9 UML support?

Tags: netbeans, ide, uml, netbeans-6.9, netbeans6.7

Is there a simple way to have UML with Netbeans 6.9 or it's easier to roll back to Netbeans 6.7 which worked great?

Thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, you can install UML plugin and start using in 6.9.1 version. You can download --
http://dlc.sun.com.edgesuite.net/netbeans/6.9/rc/zip.html

Comment: it's 6.9 rc, will it work with a normal version of 6.9 and not the release candidate?

Comment: Where can the zip be extracted? By using an update URL (not the zip), the UML plugins shows on the list but it is not installable (button disabled). Any news on this?

Comment: try extracting the zip file under netbeans installation folder.